# Adding a dropdown or toggle button to DataGrid

Tags: gwt, gwtbootstrap3

Is there a way to add a dropdown button or toggle button to the `CellTable` or `DataGrid`?

The documentation only demonstrates using a regular button (`ButtonCell`).

Answer (score 0):

To add a ToggleButton to a grid, the only way I found is to place the button in another panel (like a FlowPanel) then add this panel in the grid.

To found this type of button, you can visit the showcase of gwt :

http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomButton

here my code to have your button in a FlowPanel :

```
RootLayoutPanel rp = RootLayoutPanel.get();
FlowPanel togglePanel = new FlowPanel();
ToggleButton toggle = new ToggleButton("Coucou");
toggle.setWidth("100px");
togglePanel.add(toggle);
rp.add(togglePanel);
```

css :

```
.gwt-ToggleButton-up,
.gwt-ToggleButton-up-hovering,
.gwt-ToggleButton-up-disabled,
.gwt-ToggleButton-down,
.gwt-ToggleButton-down-hovering,
.gwt-ToggleButton-down-disabled {
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url("images/hborder.png") repeat-x 0px -27px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.gwt-ToggleButton-up,
.gwt-ToggleButton-up-hovering,
.gwt-ToggleButton-up-disabled {
  padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
}

.gwt-ToggleButton-up {
  border:1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

.gwt-ToggleButton-up-hovering {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #939393;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

.gwt-ToggleButton-up-disabled {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  cursor: default;
  opacity: .5;
  zoom: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=45);
}

.gwt-ToggleButton-down,
.gwt-ToggleButton-down-hovering,
.gwt-ToggleButton-down-disabled {
  padding: 4px 4px 2px 6px;
}

.gwt-ToggleButton-down {
  background-position: 0 -513px;
  border: 1px inset #666;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

.gwt-ToggleButton-down-hovering {
  background-position: 0 -513px;
  border: 1px inset;
  border-color: #9cf #69e #69e #7af;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

.gwt-ToggleButton-down-disabled {
  background-position: 0 -513px;
  border: 1px inset #ccc;
  cursor: default;
  opacity: .5;
  zoom: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=45);
}
```

It is the basic css i took on the showcase. You should modify it.

Comment: thanks but I am looking for a GWTBootstrap implementation :(

Comment: I'm not sure it exist...
or what you want is just add your panel to the bootstrap grid ?

Comment: Just found the data grid ! Don't forgot that you got examples with source code in the showcase. Here for the data grid : http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid